# Which button was tapped... iPhone and Obj-C question

Tags: objective-c, iphone, function, uibutton

I'm a newbie just begun with iPhone and Obj-C for a month now.

I have two buttons, both of them call the same function as follows

```
[play addTarget:self action:@selector(showQstn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Inside the function showQstn, I want to know what button was tapped. Any idea?
Alternate ideas are welcome too.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `showQstn:` is declared as

```
-(void) showQstn:(id)sender;
```

The argument `sender` is the trigger object of the event.

EDIT: You can also distinguish between the buttons using the [`tag` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag).  Each view has a unique `tag` identifier (which can be set programatically or through Interface Builder).

EDIT:
`UIButton` does not have a `title` property, hence you getting the error.  It has a [`titleForState:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleForState:).  So you should change your code to the following:

```
NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
if ([title isEqualToString:@"PLAY!"]) {
  name.text = title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the clicked button as the argument to your IBAction method showQstn:. You might consider setting the tag on the buttons, then using [sender tag] to identify which one triggered the IBAction method.